# How can I split a pandas string column using different key words?

Tags: regex, pandas, split

I need to split a column (part of a pandas dataframe) into columns described within the cell. I tried with split(":") but it splits where there are hours. Any suggestions, please? I want to go from this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njk5Y.png)

```
DOSE: 20 mg - ROUTE: oral  (morning) - START: 01/Jan/20 15:39:00
```

to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO5r5.png)

```
Dose     Route           Start                 Stop
20 mg    oral(morning)  01/jan/20  15:39:00    01/07/2020  15:39:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pattern = r"^DOSE:\s*(?P<Dose>.*?)\W+ROUTE:\s*(?P<Route>.*?)\W+START:\s*(?P<Start>.*?)(?:\W+STOP:\s*(?P<Stop>.*)|$)"
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Description':["DOSE: 20 mg - ROUTE: oral  (morning) - START: 01/Jan/20 15:39:00", "DOSE: 20 mg - ROUTE: oral  (morning) - START: 01/Jan/20 15:39:00 STOP: 05/Feb/20 12:33:45"]})
>>> df["Description"].str.extract(pattern).fillna("")
    Dose           Route               Start                Stop
0  20 mg  oral  (morning  01/Jan/20 15:39:00                    
1  20 mg  oral  (morning  01/Jan/20 15:39:00  05/Feb/20 12:33:45
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pLAmii/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `DOSE:`  -  a literal text
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?P<Dose>.*?)` - Group "Dose": any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\W+` - one or more non-word chars
- `ROUTE:\s*` - `ROUTE:` and zero or more whitespace
- `(?P<Route>.*?)` - Group "Route": any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\W+START:\s*` - one or more non-word chars, `START:` and zero or more whitespace
- `(?P<Start>.*?)` - Group "Start": any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\W+STOP:\s*(?P<Stop>.*)|$)` - either

  - `\W+STOP:\s*(?P<Stop>.*)` - one or more non-word chars, `STOP:` and zero or more whitespace and then Group "Stop" capturing any zero or more chars, as few as possible
  - `|` - or
  - `$` - end of string.